# Python ordering a dictionary value

Tags: python

I have this response from a web request:

```
{'Changes': [{'StartColumn': 34, 'StartLine': 8, 'EndLine': 8, 'NewText': '\n        ', 'EndColumn': 34}, {'StartColumn': 13, 'StartLine': 9, 'EndLine': 9, 'NewText': '', 'EndColumn': 17}, {'StartColumn': 13, 'StartLine': 10, 'EndLine': 10, 'NewText': '', 'EndColumn': 17}]}
```

In my Python dictionary I get access to the value by `data['Changes']` and can loop over each item.

What I would like to do is order the value of `Changes` to be be ordered by `EndLine` descending. I looked at `Sorted` with `Reverse=True` but I couldn't get it to work.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use sorted over the value (the list) for key "Changes".

My guess is that you call sorted over the complete dict currently, which is why it doesn't work.

```
In [1]: d = {'Changes': [{'StartColumn': 34, 'StartLine': 8, 'EndLine': 8, 'NewText': '\n        ', 'EndColumn': 34}, {'StartColumn': 13, 'StartLine': 9, 'EndLine': 9, 'NewText': '', 'EndColumn': 17}, {'StartColumn': 13, 'StartLine': 10, 'EndLine': 10, 'NewText': '', 'EndColumn': 17}]}

In [2]: d["Changes"] = sorted(d["Changes"], key= lambda x: x["EndLine"], reverse=True)

In [3]: d["Changes"]
Out[3]: 
[{'EndColumn': 17,
  'EndLine': 10,
  'NewText': '',
  'StartColumn': 13,
  'StartLine': 10},
 {'EndColumn': 17,
  'EndLine': 9,
  'NewText': '',
  'StartColumn': 13,
  'StartLine': 9},
 {'EndColumn': 34,
  'EndLine': 8,
  'NewText': '\n        ',
  'StartColumn': 34,
  'StartLine': 8}]
```

As @Andrea points out, in this situation we could use `.sort()` to do this in place, and do away with the overhead of creating a new list

```
In [4]: d = {'Changes': [{'StartColumn': 34, 'StartLine': 8, 'EndLine': 8, 'NewText': '\n        ', 'EndColumn': 34}, {'StartColumn': 13, 'StartLine': 9, 'EndLine': 9, 'NewText': '', 'EndColumn': 17}, {'StartColumn': 13, 'StartLine': 10, 'EndLine': 10, 'NewText': '', 'EndColumn': 17}]}

In [5]: d["Changes"].sort(key=lambda x: x["EndLine"], reverse=True)

In [6]: d["Changes"]
Out[6]: 
[{'EndColumn': 17,
  'EndLine': 10,
  'NewText': '',
  'StartColumn': 13,
  'StartLine': 10},
 {'EndColumn': 17,
  'EndLine': 9,
  'NewText': '',
  'StartColumn': 13,
  'StartLine': 9},
 {'EndColumn': 34,
  'EndLine': 8,
  'NewText': '\n        ',
  'StartColumn': 34,
  'StartLine': 8}]
```

Comment: You can also use `.sort()` without the overhead of creating a new list.

Comment: Thanks, I  think I was going wrong with index based keys in the lambda